# Oracle 11gR2 - Export - Import (expdp, impdp) How To Exclude A Table Partiton And This Table's Indexes

Tags: oracle, partitioning, import, export, datapump

I have a table partition (135GB) and index partition on this table (total=150GB) and I want to exclude owner schema of this table and indexes with excluding this table partition and it's indexes.

What is the correct syntax for this?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit confusing.  You say you want to "exclude owner schema of this table", but then go on to say "with excluding *this* table partition and it's indexes"  (italics/emphasis mine).  If you exclude the owner, you will certainly exclude that table .. along with all other objects under that owner/schema.

That said, the expdp 'exclude' command appears to have enough flexibility to do what you want.  It's in the official docs, at https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_export.htm#SUTIL847

Comment: Hi sir. I want to exclude table and this table's indexes. How can I do this?

Comment: Did you read the doc I linked to?  What part of that are you having difficulty understanding?

Comment: I have a syntax error.

Comment: nohup expdp "'/ as sysdba'" directory=EXP_DIR DUMPFILE=A.dmp LOGFILE=Alog.log schemas=A1 EXCLUDE=TABLE:\"= \'A_1\'\" & EXCLUDE=INDEX:\"IN (\'A_I1\', \'A_I2\', \'A_I3\')\" &

Comment: First, just to simplfy, don't try to nohup this.  Next, the doc says "Do not invoke Export as SYSDBA, except at the request of Oracle technical support. SYSDBA is used internally and has specialized functions; its behavior is not the same as for general users."  Third, how does your use of what apperas to be some strange regular expression in your 'exclude' match to what the doc specifies? Fifth, you say you have a syntax error, but you don't report exactly what it says.

Comment: I solved. Thank you Ed.

Comment: So what was the solution?

Comment: It didn't accept two different type exclude and I completed in two parts.